# Difference between 'With A as' and 'as A' in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a Database named Students, with the attribute 'Grade' to store the grades of students.
I wrote 2 following spinnets of code and expected that I would have the same result:

1.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.Students) AS A
WHERE A.Grade = (SELECT MAX(Grade) FROM A)
```

2. 

```
WITH A AS (SELECT * FROM Students)
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE A.Grade = (SELECT MAX(Grade) FROM A)
```

But actually, when I executed the first code, I got an error like "*Invalid object name 'A'.*"
I cannot understand why I got that error because I think the logic of the two codes is the same. Can anyone explain this to me, please!!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: what dbms are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You name a subquery here:

```
...(SELECT * FROM dbo.Students) AS A -- here
```

, but use this alias (*A*) inside same query here:

```
...(SELECT MAX(Grade) FROM A) -- here
```

It's not allowed.
When you use a CTE (*WITH A AS...*), you claim *A* at first and then use it properly.